# Selenium IDEのテストケースをコマンドラインで変換したい

Tags: テスト, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Seleniumでの自動テストの導入を考えています。
しかし、テストケースを記述する人はプログラマーではないため、Selenium IDEを使ってテストケースを作成しようと考えています。

これをWebDriverに変換してテストしたいのですが、コマンドライン上で変換する方法が分かりません。
検索してみると、一様にSelenium IDEでエクスポートしろと出てきます。
テストケースは修正する可能性があるため、エクスポートしてしまうとSelenium IDEで読み込めないので、書き換えたときに上書き保存とエクスポートの2回保存作業が必要となります。
エクスポートを忘れる可能性や、エクスポートだけして上書き保存を忘れる可能性を無くしたいので、修正後の保存作業は上書き保存だけとし、テストを実行する際に一括で変換を掛けたいのです。

何か良い方法・ツールは有りますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDEで記録したテストスクリプトをそのまま(seleneseと呼ぶそうでHTML形式で記録されたスクリプトのことです)使用して実行したいのであれば　[Selenese Runner Java](https://github.com/vmi/selenese-runner-java) を使うというのはどうでしょうか？

使い方は　SeleniumRCに似ていますが、内部的にはwebDriverを使用しています。
開発も日本の方が行われています。

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE以外にSelenium BuilderというSeleniumの記録・再生ツールがありますが、テストケースとWebDriver用のファイルがやはり分かれてしまうかと思います。
コミュニティの方に聞いてみると良い回答が得られるかもしれません。

日本Seleniumユーザーコミュニティ
http://www.selenium.jp/